# Pandas - Finding percentage of values in each group

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file like below.

```
Beat,Hour,Month,Primary Type,COUNTER
111,10AM,Apr,ASSAULT,12
111,10AM,Apr,BATTERY,5
111,10AM,Apr,BURGLARY,1
111,10AM,Apr,CRIMINAL DAMAGE,4
111,10AM,Aug,MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT,2
111,10AM,Aug,NARCOTICS,1
111,10AM,Aug,OTHER OFFENSE,18
111,10AM,Aug,THEFT,38
```

Now I want to find the % of each Primary Type grouped by the first three columns. For eg, For Beat = 111, Hour=10AM, Month=Apr, %Assault=12/(12+5+1+4) * 100. Can anyone give a clue on how to do this using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `transform` sum

```
df['New']=df.COUNTER/df.groupby(['Beat','Hour','Month']).COUNTER.transform('sum')*100
df
Out[575]: 
   Beat  Hour Month         Primary Type  COUNTER        New
0   111  10AM   Apr              ASSAULT       12  54.545455
1   111  10AM   Apr              BATTERY        5  22.727273
2   111  10AM   Apr             BURGLARY        1   4.545455
3   111  10AM   Apr      CRIMINAL DAMAGE        4  18.181818
4   111  10AM   Aug  MOTOR VEHICLE THEFT        2   3.389831
5   111  10AM   Aug            NARCOTICS        1   1.694915
6   111  10AM   Aug        OTHER OFFENSE       18  30.508475
7   111  10AM   Aug                THEFT       38  64.406780
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped.

Comment: @buddingengineer yw ~ :-) happy coding